# django model no column error in a field with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have custom user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):  
     model fields
```

and another model which has a field with foreign key relation to User

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='comment_writer')
    contents = models.TextField(max_length=300,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

but when I makemigrations and migrate the app and the project, I still get error message at the admin page

OperationalError at /admin/User/comment/
no such column: User_comment.writer_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/User/comment/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such column: User_comment.writer_id
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:
['/home/potentad/Documents/timesello',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/potentad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onedrived-2.0.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zgitignore-1.0.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tabulate-0.8.7-py3.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil-5.7.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 22 May 2020 23:20:23 +0000

What's wrong and what should I do ?

Comment: Did you make migrations, and migrate the database?

Comment: share migration files if you have already run ```make migrations```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes. makemigrations and then migrate

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this lines

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

after

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: then it says 
no such table: User_user
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
What's wrong?